# Empty Response from Finding Ebay API

Tags: python, ebay-api

I'm a beginner and I would like to code something to get the average selling price of a product on Ebay.

I have decided to use the Finding API and after reading the documentation I have implemented this :

```
import requests

def get_average_selling_price(research_title, num_sales):
    #url = "https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1"
    url = "https://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1"
    headers = {
        "X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION": "1.0.0",
        "X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID" : "EBAY-FR",
        "X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME": APP-ID,
        "X-EBAY-SOA-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON",
        "REST-PAYLOAD": "true",
    }
    params = {
        "X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME": "findItemsByKeywords",
        "keywords": research_title,
        "itemFilter(0).name": "SoldItemsOnly",
        "itemFilter(0).value": "true",
        "paginationInput.entriesPerPage": num_sales,
    }

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()
        #print(response.text)
        result = response.json()

        if "findItemsByKeywordsResponse" in result:
            items = result["findItemsByKeywordsResponse"][0].get("searchResult", [{}])[0].get("item", [])

            if len(items) == 0:
                print("No sales found for the specified item.")
                return

            total_price = sum(float(item["sellingStatus"][0]["convertedCurrentPrice"][0]["__value__"]) for item in items)
            average_price = total_price / len(items)

            print(f"Average Selling Price: ${average_price:.2f}")
        else:
            print("Invalid response received from the eBay API.")

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("An error occurred during API requests:")
        print(e)


# Example usage
research_title = input("Enter the research title: ")
num_sales = int(input("Enter the number of sales to consider: "))
get_average_selling_price(research_title, num_sales)
```

When running with any input I get the "No sales found for the specified item" corresponding to my error handling. Here is the content of the raw response :
{"findItemsByKeywordsResponse":[{"ack":["Success"],"version":["1.13.0"],"timestamp":["2023-07-05T13:04:08.280Z"],"searchResult":[{"@count":"0"}],"paginationOutput":[{"pageNumber":["0"],"entriesPerPage":["5"],"totalPages":["0"],"totalEntries":["0"]}],"itemSearchURL":["https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=noctali&_ddo=1&_ipg=5&_pgn=1"]}]}

I don't know why the response is empty and there is no entry. I'm a bit lost..